# Handling and syncing own custom version of an open source library with SVN

Tags: svn, open-source, repository

I found an open source library that seems quite useful in my project. The library is however in alfa/beta state and is a bit immature. It happened that I had to manually apply a patch or make some changes completely on my own in order to get rid of some minor bugs in that lib.

The question is: **how can I store and manage my custom "branch" in my SVN repository?**

**I'd like to keep my custom changes (that may eventually be checked into trunk by project owners) as well as I want to be able merge my version with official trunk (they may have improved something, etc).**

What I already did is marking a folder (let's say Resources) with an appropriate svn:externals property. I can then  update from official trunk "from within" a working copy bound to my repo. Obviously what I cannot do is commiting the changes. 
Seems like nothing (temporarly relocating, switching, ...) works. I even tried exporting into other folder, then making my changes and then "somehow" merging it but the only result was a bunch of errors, most of them complaining about the repo guids mismatch. But maybe I missed some detail :).

So any ideas how to use an  **always up-to-date** third party open source library and manage own customizations?
I don't consider storing only .patch files in my repo as an option ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you cannot branch between repositories exactly, you *can* import the code in your own repository, and then perform [merges between repositories](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2008/03/do-not-post-mer.html). (The linked post implies that there are problems with this feature, but I believe it is fully supported in the latest SVN releases. SVN 1.6.1 had a [bug fix](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3383) related to this scenario.)

The SVN book describes a more general strategy which does not make use of cross-repository merges. It also works if the 3rd party code does not live in a SVN repository at all. See the section on [Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check out Piston, it does exactly what you want with ease.

http://piston.rubyforge.org/

I use it to maintain an upstream repository and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SVN you can use a distributed version control software. For example [Git](http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/) supports synchronizing branches with an SVN repository.